# Selecting Tags From the UI not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am very new in Laravel. I'm trying to bind a property of the Model to selected values of the select tag. now, the following code can not show the selected tags.

```
{!! Form::label('tag_list','Tags') !!}
    {!! Form::select('tag_list[]',$tags, null,['class'=>'form-control','multiple']) !!}
```

when I gave

```
{!! Form::label('tag_list','Tags') !!}
        {!! Form::select('tag_list[]',$tags, [1,2,3],['class'=>'form-control','multiple']) !!}
```

it worked.

in model Article I have

```
 public function getTagListAttribute()
        {
return $this->tags->lists('id')->all();
        }
```

this does not help. In some thread I found that for Laravel 5.2 pluck should work instead of list. 
so I tried

public function getTagListAttribute()

```
     {
         return $this->tags()->pluck("id")->toArray();
     }
```

I am using Laravel 5.2.39. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of the select() method should contain the default value(s) of the select. You're passing null so there are no default values which will be selected automatically.So that it gives you error.

You can write your model as

```
public function getTagListAttribute()
        {
return $this->tags->lists('id')->toArray();
        }
```